# pandas drops index index on merge in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am merging two dataframes using `merge(..., how='left')` since I want to retain only entries that match up with the "left" dataframe. The problem is that the merge operation seems to drop the index of my leftmost dataframe, shown here:

```
import pandas
df1 = pandas.DataFrame([{"id": 1,
                         "name": "bob"},
                        {"id": 10,
                         "name": "sally"}])
df1 = df1.set_index("id")
df2 = pandas.DataFrame([{"name": "bob",
                         "age": 10},
                        {"name": "sally",
                         "age": 11}])

print "df1 premerge: "
print df1
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=["name"],
                how="left")
print "merged: "
print df1
# This is not "id"
print df1.index
# And there's no "id" field
assert ("id" in df1.columns) == False
```

Before the merge, `df1` was indexed by `id`. After the merge operation, there's just the default numeric index for the merged dataframe and the `id` field was dropped. How can I do this kind of merge operation but retain the index of the leftmost dataframe?

To clarify: I want all the columns of `df2` to be added to every entry in `df1` that has the matching `id` value. If an entry in `df2` has an `id` value not in `df1`, then that shouldn't be merged in (hence the `how='left'`).

**edit**: I could as a hack do: `df1.reset_index()` but merging and then set the index again, but I prefer not to if possible, it seems like merge shouldn't have to drop the index. thanks.

Comment: You could try indexing `df1` and `df2` by name instead of id, and then use `join` instead of `merge` like this: `df1.join(df2)` which will preserve the index.

Comment: It's not possible since `name` is not unique in `df1`

Comment: Why don't you set_index after the merge?

Comment: I would but it drops the column that I want to be the index after the merge, namely `id`

Comment: If you didn't call set_index before merge, it should still be around in df1

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976503/how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge), which appears to be the same thing.  The answer there is basically the hack you talked about.

Comment: Preserve index after merge is a little bit strange while the method is "outer". So I think it's better not to preserve it.

Comment: But I see how='left'. IMO, if how='outer' there is no way to preserve index as defined by column 'id' as it would be undefined for rows unique to df2

Answer (score 5):

You've already pointed out doing a reset_index before the merge and a set_index afterwards, which works.  The only way I know of to preserve indices across a merge is for the merge to involve an index on at least one of the data frames being merged.  So here, you could do:

```
In [403]: df2 = df2.set_index('name')

In [404]: df1.merge(df2, left_on='name', right_index=True)
Out[404]: 
     name  age
id            
1     bob   10
10  sally   11
```

to merge df2's index, which we've taken from its 'name' column, against the 'name' column on df1.

This makes some sense, because otherwise the index of the resulting dataframe is ambiguous as it could come from either dataframe.