# Merging whilst keeping order in R and pandas

Tags: python, r, dataframe, pandas

I use this (somewhat kludgy) R function to merge data.frames and keep the order of one of them:

```
MergeMaintainingOrder = function(Ordered,Unordered,ByWhatColumn){
  Ordered$TEMPINDEX = 1:length(Ordered[,1])
  MergedData = merge(Ordered,Unordered,by=ByWhatColumn)
  MergedData = MergedData[order(MergedData$TEMPINDEX),]
  MergedData$TEMPINDEX = NULL
  return(MergedData)
}
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in pandas? Is there a less kludgy way or should I just rewrite the same function?

Thanks,

-N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas a merge resets the index, but you can easily work around this by resetting the index *before* doing the merge. Resetting the index will create a new column called "index" which you can then use to re-create your index after the merge. For example:

```
Ordered.reset_index().merge(Ordered, Unordered, on=ByWhatColumn).set_index('index')
```

See this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976503/how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge) for more discussion (hat tip to @WouterOvermeire)