# Delete rows from pandas DataFrame with non-unique index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to delete rows in a pandas DataFrame when the index is *not* guaranteed to be unique.

So, I want to drop items 0 and 4 from my DataFrame df.  This would be the typical code you would use to do that:

```
df.drop([0, 4].index)
```

If each index is unique, this works fine.  However, if items 0, 1, and 2 all have the same index, this code drops items 0, 1, 2, and 4, instead of just 0 and 4.

My DataFrame is set up this way for good reasons, so I don't want to restructure my data, which looks approximately like this:

```
        age
site             
mc03    0.39
mc03    0.348
mc03    0.348
mc03    0.42
mc04    0.78
```

I tried:

```
del df.iloc[0]
```

but this fails with:

```
AttributeError: __delitem__
```

Any other suggestions for how to accomplish this task?

Update:

I found two ways to do it, but neither is particularly elegant.

```
to_drop = [0, 4]
df = df.iloc[sorted(set(range(len(df))) - set(to_drop))]
# or:
df = df.iloc[[i for i in range(len(df)) if i not in to_drop]]
```

Maybe this is as good as it's going to get, though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not very elegant too, but let me post it as an alternative:

```
df = df.reset_index().drop([0, 4]).set_index("site")
```

It temporarily changes the index to a regular index, drops the rows and sets the original index back. The idea is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11982843/2285236).

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution (using numpy):

```
In [252]: mask = np.ones(len(df)).astype(bool)

In [253]: mask[[0,4]] = False

In [254]: mask
Out[254]: array([False,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [255]: df[mask]
Out[255]:
        age
mc03  0.348
mc03  0.348
mc03  0.420
```