# Changing value in pandas dataframe is same row is present in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. 2 pandas dataframes:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2' : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 'col3' : [0,2,0,-1,0]}) 
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3], 'col2' : [10, 11, 12], 'col6' : [20, 31, 12]})
```

How do I change the value in `col3` in df1 to 0 if both `col1` and `col2` have same value in df1 and df2. The result for df1 should look like this:

```
  col1  col2  col3
0     1    10     0
1     2    11     0
2     3    12     0
3     4    13    -1
4     5    14     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick numpy solution.  `i` gets indices for every combination of one row from `df1` and another row from `df2`.  I use the `==` to determine which cells are equal.  `all(2)` determines if all cells from one row equal all cells from the other row.  If true, then the corresponding set of indices represent a match.  So, `i[0][matches]` tells me all the rows from `df1` that match the rows in `df2` represented by `i[1][matches]`.  But I only need to change values in `df1` so I only use `i[0][matches]` to slice `df1` on the 3rd column then assign `0`.

```
def pir(df1, df2):
    i = np.indices((len(df1), len(df2)))
    matches = (df2.values[i[1], :2] == df1.values[i[0], :2]).all(2)
    df = df1.copy()
    df.iloc[i[0][matches], 2] = 0
    return df

pir(df1, df2)
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

```
def ayhan(df1, df2):
    df1 = df1.copy()
    df1.loc[df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on=['col1', 'col2'])['index'], 'col3'] = 0
    return df1
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @piRSquared, what does this line do: `  matches = (df2.values[i[1], :2] == df1.values[i[0], :2]).all(2)`

Comment: It's quick for very small data frames. For larger (>1e5 rows) may be impractical because it's effectively a Cartesian product. Even for a moderate sized frames, `merge` should perform better.

Answer (score 2):

If you merge two DataFrames on `col1` and `col2`, the resulting DataFrame will have rows where both DataFrames have the same value in those columns. However, pandas [loses the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976503/how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge) when merging. You can use `reset_index` prior to merging to keep the index and use that index in `.loc`:

```
df1.loc[df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on=['col1', 'col2'])['index'], 'col3'] = 0

df1
Out: 
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    10     0
1     2    11     0
2     3    12     0
3     4    13    -1
4     5    14     0
```