# Merge daily values into intraday DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two `DataFrames`: `intraday` which has one row per minute, and `daily` which has one row per day.

How can I add a column `intraday['some_val']` where `some_val` is taken from the `daily['some_val']` row where the `intraday.index` value (date component) equals the `daily.index` value (date component)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following setup,

```
intraday = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-01-07', freq='T'))
daily = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01', '2016-01-07', freq='D'))
daily['some_val'] = np.arange(daily.shape[0])
```

you can create a column from the date component of both indices, and merge on that column

```
daily['date'] = daily.index.date
intraday['date'] = intraday.index.date    
daily.merge(intraday)
```

```
            date  some_val
0     2016-01-01         0
1     2016-01-01         0
2     2016-01-01         0
3     2016-01-01         0
4     2016-01-01         0
...          ...       ...
8636  2016-01-06         5
8637  2016-01-06         5
8638  2016-01-06         5
8639  2016-01-06         5
8640  2016-01-07         6
```

---

Alternatively, you can take advantage of automatic index alignment, and use `fillna`.

```
intraday['some_val'] = daily['some_val']
intraday.fillna(method='ffill', downcast='infer')
```

```
                     some_val
2016-01-01 00:00:00         0
2016-01-01 00:01:00         0
2016-01-01 00:02:00         0
2016-01-01 00:03:00         0
2016-01-01 00:04:00         0
...                       ...
2016-01-06 23:56:00         5
2016-01-06 23:57:00         5
2016-01-06 23:58:00         5
2016-01-06 23:59:00         5
2016-01-07 00:00:00         6
```

Note that this only works if the time component of your `daily` index is `00:00`.

Comment: How can we `merge` to produce a DataFrame with the same index as the higher-frequency DF (`intraday` in this case)?  The first example produces an iterative index and appears to discard the `intraday` index.  Note also: The second example works if and only if at least one exact same DateTime occurs in the lower frequency of both DataFrames.  E.g., if `intraday` doesn't contain `00:00` each day it will fail even though the `daily` index does.

Comment: In this case you can just use `daily.merge(intraday).set_index(intraday.index)`. Seems that you can't ask `merge` to keep the index of one of the data frames (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976503/how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge)).