# Pandas Merge DataFrames without rows overlap

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like these:

[image]

[image]

They have the same columns.

Since I am broadcasting an API, they usually hava some overlap, which can be handled by the `tradeID` which is unique.

I have tried some stuff like:

`df2 = df0.join(df1, how='outer', lsuffix='_caller', rsuffix='_other')`

and

`df2 = df0.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

But the results are respectively:

[image]

and[image]

I am looking for a union without overlap, could someone help me?

Comment: So when a `tradeID` is present in both data frames, what do you expect to appear in the merged result?

Comment: @IgorRaush, both rows would be exactly the same, I would like to keep just one of them, please also note that `tradeID` is an index

Comment: the code: `df2 = df0.merge(df1, how='outer')` works but it throws my indexes away

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like [combine_first()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) should do it for you:

```
df2 = df0.combine_first(df1)
```

...where `df0` takes precedence over `df1` when the indicies match.  Although in your case, if they're identical, it doesn't really matter.  But if they're not identical, that's how `combine_first()` works.

The following is an example of it working with dummy data.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

a = io.StringIO(u'''
tradeID,amount,date
X001,100,1/1/2016
X002,200,1/2/2016
X003,300,1/3/2016
X005,500,1/5/2016
''')

b = io.StringIO(u'''
tradeID,amount,date
X004,400,1/4/2016
X005,500,1/5/2016
X006,600,1/6/2016
''')

dfA = pd.read_csv(a, index_col = 'tradeID')
dfB = pd.read_csv(b, index_col = 'tradeID')

df = dfA.combine_first(dfB)
```

**Output:**

```
         amount      date
tradeID                  
X001      100.0  1/1/2016
X002      200.0  1/2/2016
X003      300.0  1/3/2016
X004      400.0  1/4/2016
X005      500.0  1/5/2016
X006      600.0  1/6/2016
```

If you really want to use `merge` you can still do that, but you'll need to add some syntax to keep your indicies ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976503/how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge)):

```
df = dfA.reset_index().merge(dfB.reset_index(), how = 'outer').set_index('tradeID')
```

I ran super rudimentary timing on these two options and `combine_first()` consistently beat `merge` by nearly 3x on this very small data set.

...and Igor Raush's version tested at or slightly faster than `combine_first()`.

Comment: awesome! it worked exactly like i needed! thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is

```
pd.concat([df0, df1]).loc[lambda df: ~df.index.duplicated()]
```