# python/pandas merge two dataframes if both exist in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python/pandas and I had a question of merging two dataframes together.

Consider I had

```
df1:

            Portfolio Value
Date                       
2016-07-01     100000
2016-07-08     100005
2016-07-15     100010
2016-07-22     100015
2016-07-29     100020
2016-08-05     100025
2016-08-12     100030
2016-08-19     100035
2016-08-26     100040
2016-09-02     100045
2016-09-09     100050
2016-09-16     100055
2016-09-23     100060
2016-09-30     100065
2016-10-07     100070
2016-10-14     100075
2016-10-21     100080
```

and

```
df2:
   Portfolio Value
0     100015
1     100030
2     100040
3     100075
```

I would like to result in a dataframe that keeps the values and date of `df1` that also exists in `df2` as shown below:

```
newdf:

            Portfolio Value
Date                       
2016-07-22     100015
2016-08-12     100030
2016-08-26     100040
2016-10-14     100075
```

I believe that this a merge, but I am not certain. If any other implementation would be better that is fine as well.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

an inner join was attempted as shown in the possible duplicate by the first comment but it does not keep the date index. Is there a way to get the dates with the Portfolio Values to show as well?

Comment: @Abhishek, I apologize I did not realize that there might be a solution. However, if i do the innerjoin as shown in the link the Date index does not not remain is there a way that I can keep the Date index of `df1`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976503/how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge

Comment: `df2.merge(df1.reset_index(), on='Portfolio Value').set_index('Date')`