# How to merge in pandas multiindex (name, date) with a column date, while keeping the multi-index?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two pandas dataframes. df1 is indexed by a multi-index (name, date). df2 is a simple 0 to n index with a 'Date' column. My question is how I can merge these two dataframes by date, while keeping the multi-index.

I used following command to merge. The merged dataframe don't have the multi-index anymore.

```
 df_merg = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='date', righ_on='Date')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep index when using pandas merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976503/how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to `reset_index` for df1 before merge and `set_index` for df_merg after merge

```py
df1.reset_index(level=['name', 'date'], inplace=True)
df_merg = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='date', right_on='Date')
df_merg = df_merg.set_index(['name', 'date'])
```