# Merging columns retain multi-index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I love and multi index HOWEVER some functions are only work by collapsing the index, which is my main frustration with Pandas, all pandas documentation always focuses on single index frames. Below is an example data frame where I want to merge the two data frames on the postcode, however I do not want to lose the multi index by resetting the index, merging the data and setting the index up again.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Postcode' : ["", "", 'A1 1UU', 'G1 2EE', "","", 'EF2 5GG',"",""] }, 
                    index=[[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,], 
                            ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Postcode' : ['A1 1UU', 'G1 2EE', 'EF2 5GG',],
                   "Map Position" : ["51.499767, -0.127262", 
                                     "51.500923, -0.124628", 
                                     "51.503195, -0.118710"]})
```

The result should be below

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'Postcode' : ["", "", 'A1 1UU', 'G1 2EE', "","", 'EF2 5GG',"",""], 
                   "Map Position" : ["","", "51.499767, -0.127262", 
                                     "51.500923, -0.124628", "", "", 
                                     "51.503195, -0.118710", "", ""]}, 
                    index=[[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,], 
                            ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']])
```

Tried:
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Postcode', how='left')

However result is loosing the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Postcode' : ["", "", 'A1 1UU', 'G1 2EE', "","", 'EF2 5GG',"",""] }, 
                    index=[[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,], 
                            ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Postcode' : ['A1 1UU', 'G1 2EE', 'EF2 5GG',],
                   "Map Position" : ["51.499767, -0.127262", 
                                     "51.500923, -0.124628", 
                                     "51.503195, -0.118710"]})

# Set Postcode as the index for df2 for joining
df2.set_index('Postcode', inplace=True)

# Use join with 'Postcode' as the key to join on
result = df1.join(df2, on='Postcode', how='left')

# Fill NaNs with empty strings
result['Map Position'].fillna("", inplace=True)

print(result)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. A lot of answers require reset_index then to do the merge then to .set_index. Thanks for the help @Amira

Answer (score 1):

That's the normal behaviour in case of a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) on columns :

> `pd.merge(...)`
>
> Merge DataFrame or named Series objects with a database-style join... The join is done on columns or indexes. **If joining columns on columns,
> the DataFrame indexes will be ignored.**

To preserve the MultiIndex of`df1`, I would do it this way :

```
O, T = "Postcode", "Map Position" # Origin & Target

out = df1.assign(**{T: df1[O].map(df2.set_index(O)[T]).fillna("")})
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    Postcode          Map Position
1 A                               
  B                               
  C   A1 1UU  51.499767, -0.127262
2 A   G1 2EE  51.500923, -0.124628
  B                               
  C                               
3 A  EF2 5GG  51.503195, -0.118710
  B                               
  C
```

Comment: **NB**: This is likey a duplicate of this *Q&A* : [how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976503/how-to-keep-index-when-using-pandas-merge)